# How to use a shared ViewModel, and avoid reusing the same instance of it every time with Navigation Component

Tags: android, dagger, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

My app consists of one single `Activity` with multiple `Fragments`, following the "single Activity app model", so that I can implement properly navigation using the `Navigation Component` in Android `jetpack`.

Most of my screens (`Fragments`) are standalone and don't depend on each other, hence they use their own `ViewModel`

Some features require navigation involving more than one `Fragment`. As those features share data between them that are passed back and forth through the `Fragments`, I use a **shared ViewModel** (as recommended by Google). 
I need to use the same instance of the shared `ViewModel` in all the associated `Fragments`, as I need the `Fragments` share the state of the shared `ViewModel`.

To use the same instance of the `ViewModel` in these associated `Fragments`, I need to create the `ViewModel` using the parent `Activity` (not the `Fragment`) when getting the `ViewModel` from the `ViewModelProviders`:

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(
            parentActivity, factory.create()
        ).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

This works, however, It produces one problem: 
when navigating a consecutive times to the first `Fragment` that requires the shared `ViewModel`, `ViewModelProviders.of()` will return the same instance of the `ViewModel` as before: The `ViewModel` is being shared between the `Fragments`, but also between different navigations to the feature implemented like this.

I understand why this is happening (Android is storing the ViewModel in a `map`, which is being used when requesting the `ViewModel` with `ViewModelProviders.of()`), but I don't know how I am expected to implement the "shared ViewModel pattern" properly.

The only workarounds I see are:

- Create a different `Activity` for the feature that uses the `Fragment` with a shared `ViewModel`
- Use nested `Fragments`, and use common parent `Fragment` for the feature that uses the `Fragment` with a shared `ViewModel`

With these two options, I would be able to create a `ViewModel` that will be shared between the `Fragments` intervening in the feature, and will be different each time I navigate to the feature.

The problem I see here is that this seems to be that against the fundamentals of the `Navigation Component` and the single `Activity` app. 
Each feature implemented this way will need to have a different navigation graph, as they will use a different navigation host. This would prevent me from using some of the nice features of `Navigation Component`.

What is the proper way to implement what I want? 
Am I missing anything, or is it the way it is?

Before `Navigation Component` I would use different `Activities` and `Fragments` and use `Dagger` scopes associated with the `Activity`/`Fragment` to achieve this. But I'm not sure what's the best way of implementing this with just one Activity`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have discovered this can be done starting with `2.1.0-alpha02`

From: 
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.1.0-alpha02

> You can now create ViewModels that are scoped at a navigation graph
>   level via the by navGraphViewModels() property delegate for Kotlin
>   users or by using the getViewModelStore() API added to NavController.
>   b/111614463

Basically:

1. in the nav graph editor, create a nested graph, assigning one id to it
2. when providing the `ViewModel`, do not do it from the Activity. Instead, use
   the `navGraphViewModels` extension function of `Fragment`.

Example:

Nested graph in the nav graph

```
<navigation
        android:id="@+id/feature_nested_graph"
        android:label="Feature"
        app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">
        <argument
            android:name="item_id"
            app:argType="integer" />
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
            [....]
        </fragment>
        [....]
    </navigation>
```

For getting the `ViewModel` scoped to `feature_nested_graph` nested nav gaph:

```
        val viewModel: SharedViewModel
                by fragment.navGraphViewModels(R.id.feature_nested_graph)
```

or, if are injecting into the `ViewModel` and you are using a custom factory for that:

```
        val viewModel: SharedViewModel
                by fragment.navGraphViewModels(R.id.feature_nested_graph) { factory2.create(assessmentId) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the same instance of a shared `ViewModel`, because it belongs to the `Activity` - that's clear. I don't know exactly your use case, but usually when I need to do similar, I simply notify the `ViewModel` from `Fragment's` `onCreate` or `orCreateView` passing some identifier. In your case it could be something like:

```
viewModel.onNavigatedTo("fragment1")
```

This way the shared view model can differentiate what fragment currently uses it and refresh the state accordingly.